# How to stop receiving "Google Groups: Message Pending" emails?

Tags: google-groups

I was added as a manager to a group I joined and since that I started to receive `Google Groups: Message Pending` emails.

How can I turn off receiving such email but stay in the manager role?

Answer (score 2):

There does not seem to be a way to disable those emails, as long as you have the moderator permission.
What you could do, is ask the group administrator to create a new role which has all your current permissions, minus `Approve messages`. That way, you should be able to do most of the things you can do now on the group, but you will not be able to moderate messages, and you will not receive those emails.

Ask the moderator to go to `https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!managemembers/[your-group-name]/creategroup` to set up a new role, and refer to the [documentation](http://support.google.com/groups/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=2466367).

Answer (score 0):

You could also create a filter on your own account to send those messages to spam, trash or an specific folder. Cheers.

Comment: How do you do that? Please include directions to help your answer make sense to more users.

Comment: @Andrew Lott: any such directions would be far off-topic because setting up email filters is different for each email client. consult your email software docu

Comment: Oh, I meant within the Google account.